# Closure of Subset of Ordered square

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=[(x,x^2):x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}]$ be a subset of the ordered square $I_0^2$. How would you find the closure of this set? My first guess would be a parabola, but I'm not entirely comfortable with finding closures of the ordered square.

Comment: What is "the ordered square"?  Is that $[0,1]^2$ with the lexicographic order?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant.

Comment: What have you thought? I don't think it will be the parabola as a rational point $q$ will have a neighborhood disjoint from A. Let $(q,q^2) \in \mathbb Q ^2$ then $q \times (q^2 - \epsilon, q^2 + \epsilon)$ doesn't intersect A.

Comment: Would <0,1> be a limit point? @LeoLerena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of $A$ is $A\cup ((0,1]\times \{0\})\cup ([1,0)\times \{1\}$. Check that open intervals around these extra “endpoints” all contain points of $A$. All points with second coordinate in $(0,1)$ that don’t already lie in $A$ are not in the closure.

Comment: Can you specify what the set of limit points are?

Comment: @JB071098 all extra points in the closure are, by definition. No point of $A$ is a limit point of $A$.